# Adjetivos de los meses

Tags: solicitud-de-término, adjetivos

Fíjense que estaba pensando sobre los adjetivos de los meses y me di cuenta que no los domino. Este es mi conocimiento actual:

| Mes | Adjetivo |
| --- | --- |
| Enero | no sé |
| Febrero | no sé |
| Marzo | no sé |
| Abril | no sé |
| Mayo | no sé |
| Junio | no sé |
| Julio | no sé |
| Agosto | no sé |
| Septiembre | no sé |
| Octubre | no sé |
| Noviembre | Noviembrino? |
| Diciembre | Decembrino |

Como podrán ver me faltan algunos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buscando con la opción "empieza por" en el DLE, solo he encontrado los siguientes (algunos de ellos propuestos por [j"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/18348/j) en un comentario):

### -

- [marceño](https://dle.rae.es/marce%C3%B1o), o [marcero](https://dle.rae.es/marcero)
- [abrileño](https://dle.rae.es/abrile%C3%B1o)
- 
- 
- 
- [agosteño](https://dle.rae.es/agoste%C3%B1o), o [agostizo](https://dle.rae.es/agostizo?m=form)
- [septembrino](https://dle.rae.es/septembrino)
- 
- 
- [decembrino](https://dle.rae.es/decembrino)

Mención especial a la palabra *octubrino*, cuyo segnificado según el DLE [no tiene nada que ver con octubre](https://dle.rae.es/octubrino), pero que se usa refirieéndose a octubre [al menos una vez al año en Guayaquil, Ecuador](https://www.ministeriodegobierno.gob.ec/fiestas-octubrinas-de-guayaquil-se-viviran-en-paz/).

Es probable que no existan todos los adjetivos, del mismo modo que no parecen existir adjetivos para los días de la semana excepto *sabático* y *dominical*.

Comment: También *marcero, agostizo* (y *germinal*).

Comment: En El Salvador, tenemos las "Fiestas Julias", celebradas en el departamento de Santa Ana, y las "Fiestas Agostinas" en el departamento de San Salvador.

Comment: Posiblemente *mayero* (‘de mayo’) https://www.elmundo.com/portal/pagina.general.impresion.php?idx=106093

Comment: Para mí, lo lógico sería que todo lo referente al martes se denominara como marciano.